# WooCommerce product attributes filter widget - Save value into user meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, user-data

Is there a way I can hook into the **product attributes drop-down filter widget** and save the chosen value into the user meta? I basically want to know what the user's last used filter was so I can default it later on.

Something like this maybe?

```
function save_attribute_filter_in_user_meta($selectedValue){

    if(is_user_logged_in()){

        $curr_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        // save/overwrite selected product attribute filter value into user meta
        update_user_meta( $curr_user_id, 'currentSelectedFilter', $selectedValue);
    }   
}
add_action('whatever_this_hook_is', 'save_attribute_filter_in_user_meta');
```

If there is no way of hooking into it, any idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: I dont think so as this is related to a live event on client side (not for PHP alone), so you need to use Javascript and ajax for that…

Comment: Bummer. If I just appended the "?filter_my-attribute=value" to the end of the URL on a shop page without the widget being there would the filtering still occur? I may just make a custom drop-box in a form that mimics the widget. @LoicTheAztec